# Numpy to reorder such that every nth row from the current row is appended to it

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

I want to reshape the Numpy array A, not by appending normal next row, but by appending every Nth row that comes after it.

Ex:

```
A = [[1  2  3  4]
[5  6  7  8]
[9  10 11 12]
[13 14 15 16]
[17 18 19 20]
[21 22 23 24]]
```

Now, I want to construct an array of size 2x12 like this from A

```
 A = [[1 2 3 4 9 10 11 12 17 18 19 10]
 [5 6 7 8 13 14 15 16 21 22 23 24]]
```

Here You can see that every 2nd row from the current row is appended to it and formed the new reshaped array.

Comment: Alternatively: `A.reshape(-1, 2, 4).swapaxes(0, 1).reshape(2, -1)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple indexing, `array.ravel()` and `np.vstack()`:

```
In [37]: np.vstack((A[::2].ravel(), A[1::2].ravel()))
Out[37]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  9, 10, 11, 12, 17, 18, 19, 20],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8, 13, 14, 15, 16, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
```

Comment: can you let me understand what r u doing?

Comment: @SurviMakharia If you know about [numpy indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) you know that the first part in index notation denotes the start, the second part is stop and third part is step. In which `[1::2]` means start from index 1 with step 2 about the other functions you can read the doc.

Answer (score 2):

How about this approach?

```
# extract alternative rows starting from 0th row (1st row)
In [18]: A[0::2]
Out[18]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12],
       [17, 18, 19, 20]])

# and then flatten to 1D array
In [19]: A[0::2].flatten()
Out[19]: array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  9, 10, 11, 12, 17, 18, 19, 20])


# extract alternative rows starting from 2nd row
In [17]: A[1::2]
Out[17]: 
array([[ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [13, 14, 15, 16],
       [21, 22, 23, 24]])


# and then flatten to 1D array
In [20]: A[1::2].flatten()
Out[20]: array([ 5,  6,  7,  8, 13, 14, 15, 16, 21, 22, 23, 24])


# to get 2D, just put them in `np.vstack` (in the order you want the final array)
In [21]: np.vstack((A[0::2].flatten(), A[1::2].flatten()))
Out[21]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  9, 10, 11, 12, 17, 18, 19, 20],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8, 13, 14, 15, 16, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
```